# Best practice for "Don't show me again" checkbox on iOS

Tags: usability, design-patterns, ios, popup, best-practice

I have a question about using checkboxes in warning message. Some users want the application to always warn them but some users do not. I want users to choose for themselves.

I tried to solve this issue by adding a checkbox in a warning popup dialog but I feel this is not the iOS way. Is there any best practice for this in iOS?

[image: Don't show me again checkbox]

Should I instead use a hint under the warning message about the user being able to do this via Settings? This would also hint to the user where they can enable /disable next time.

[image: Settings hint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this note is a good idea, on the bottom, with a small font-size, but I think it should be more clear, like "You choose to always be asked about settings. Want to change this?"

Answer (score 1):

Don't use checkboxes on the pop-up.  It would be better to use a three button pop-up with the options (but perhaps not the same texts):

- Always activate
- Activite this time
- Cancel

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVjT9I.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, users can set this behaviour as default for any application in their settings pane. Since this is a feature of iOS itself, you don't need to worry about it.

If you think that in your case, yours would want to change that settings the best approach would be to just redirect them to that part of the settings screen rather than doing it at your end of the application.